# How can I console log all rest paramaters without using a loop? (Including objects and no toString)

Tags: javascript

I got a mission that I must do which goes like this:

Write a function that does the following:
it will accept any number of arguments and do console.log on all of them.
Do not use loops.

Example and expected result:

[image: result:]

How am I supposed to do something like that without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
function consoleAll(...args) {
    console.log(...args)
}

consoleAll("hello", 2, {name : "milad"})

/*output -> "hello", 2, {
  name: "milad"
}
*/
```

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't try to add the 3 dots when I console logged the args that pretty much solved it... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple but it depends on how you want to use this data you feel? But I suppose you could run an array length and sort your checks some how.

```js
function MyHugeFunction (data) {
  console.log(`Size: ${data.length}`);
  console.log(`First Arg: ${data[0]}`);
  console.log(`Entire Argument Set: ${data}`);
};

MyHugeFunction(["test","hello","123"]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, you can literally just go `console.log(1,2,3)`

Comment: There's different ways of doing this, but the downvote I assume is a mater of opinion.

Comment: That function will not "_accept any number of arguments_". Or... technically it will _accept it_, but only the first argument is used.

Comment: It'd come down to application use and what the results required were then.

Comment: it should accept whatever not just an array of data.

Comment: An array can nest any data-type... But yes the other solution may appeal then, this is not worse nor better to be fair! :)

Comment: @BGPHiJACK This isn't meant to be production code. It's an assignment. An assignment with specific rules, which your answer is not following. There is an image (unfortunately, [we don't really like images here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)), with example input and output. This answer doesn't follow that contract.

Comment: Yes, your use case won't work here, but other solutions above that do seem like the solution. Some finer details help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious without the context but I think it is an exercise on spread operator.

In this case, your function would be something like

```
function(...args) {
  args.forEach((val) => console.log(val))
}
```

or

```
function(...args) {
  console.log(...args)
}
```

The "...args" is used to get all the arguments of your function in a "args array" and the forEach function applied to this array does the trick